# MS-SQL update the price of a particular item to be the same as another particular item in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with items and prices, where the price can be different based on a location identifier. What I would like to do is to take the price for item 123 and apply it to item 456 for all locations

```
storeid itemid price
1       123    '6.95'
1       456    '0.00'
2       123    '4.95'
2       456    '0.00'
```

The desired outcome is to have the data look like this:

```
storeid itemid price
1       123    '6.95'
1       456    '6.95'
2       123    '4.95'
2       456    '4.95'
```

The storeid and itemid are integers, and the price is a varchar 
I thought about moving all the data for 123 to a temp table, and then iterate through a while loop to update the pricing for each storeid, but was hoping there might be a more straight forward way.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ip.*,
              max(case when itemid = 123 then price end) over (partition by storeid) as new_price
      from itemprices ip
     )
update toupdate
    set price = new_price
    where toupdate.itemid = 456;
```

The traditional SQL method would be:

```
update itemprices
    set price = (select ip2.price from itemprices ip2 where ip2.storeid = ip.storeid and ip2.itemid = 123)
    where itemid = 456;
```

Or using a `join`:

```
update ip
    set price = ip123.price
    from itemprices ip join
         itemprices ip123
         on ip.storeid = ip123.storeid and ip123.itemid = 123
    where ip.itemid = 456;
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a join:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Price = t2.price
FROM table t
JOIN table t2 on t.storeid = t2.storeid
              and t2.itemid = 123
WHERE t.itemid = 456
```